# Manual Url Culture Rewriting in DotNetNuke Request

Tags: url-rewriting, localization, dotnetnuke, culture

I'm working with dotnetnuke 7.
I'm not using any rewriting modules and don't want to use them.
When content localization is enabled, url has the following view:

```
my_training_host/en-us/my-page.aspx
```

I want to change manually the display url so, that instead of full culture in query, the two letter culture (neutral culture) will show:

```
my_training_host/en/my-page.aspx
```

Does anyone have similar problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you ever change your mind about using a rewriting module, UrlMaster is the module for that. If not, then DNN 7.1 now adds support for creating url providers as extensions. More details at http://www.dnnsoftware.com/blog/cid/154604/Introducing-DNN-Extension-URL-Providers

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Open URL Rewriter](http://openurlrewriter.codeplex.com/) for DNN - it does exactly what you ask for with it's default installation - no further config required.
And it's open source in comparison with UrlMaster.

In case of you use [version 1.3.1 of Open URL Rewriter](http://openurlrewriter.codeplex.com/releases/view/611834) with [DNN 7.04](http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/releases/view/611324) to get two letters only for multilingual sites you have to make sure:

1. you create site aliases for each language with the two letter part you desire and
2. enable those entries as primary aliases (you need one primary alias for each language), for example for two languages (en & fr) you need to set three primary aliases like the following:

```
    ✔    www.yourdomain.com
    ✔    www.yourdomain.com/en    us-US
    ✔    www.yourdomain.com/fr    fr-FR
```